# plot won't appear with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Since today my plots are not appearing on my jupyter notebook (using Python 3.6).
When adding plt.show() the plot appears but in a separate tab.

How can I make the plot appear directly inline ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following worked for me

```
%matplotlib inline
```